# NHibernate. Mixing inheritance strategies

Tags: nhibernate, inheritance, mapping

I would like implement this hierarchy:

```
BaseOrder --> Order --> ConstOrder
```

My mappings:
BaseOrder.hbm

```
<class name="BaseOrder, BackOffice.Core" abstract="true">
    <id name="Id" unsaved-value="0" type="int">
      <column name="id" not-null="true"/>
      <generator class="hilo">
        <param name="max_lo">0</param>
        <param name="where">table_name = 'orders'</param>
      </generator>
    </id>

</class>
```

Order.hbm

```
<union-subclass name="Order, Transport.Core" table="order" extends="BaseOrder, BackOffice.Core">
  <property name="PeopleNum">
    <column name="people_num" length="64"/>
  </property>      
</union-subclass>
```

ConstOrder.hbm

```
 <joined-subclass name="ConstOrder, Transport.Core" table="const_order" extends="Order, Transport.Core">
      <key column="Id"/>
      <property name="PeriodType">
        <column name="period_type"/>
      </property>
    </joined-subclass>
```

Ok. I start with Table per concrete class and finish with Table per subclass.
And I've got some problems with:

```
ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(ConstOrder));
return criteria.List<ConstOrder>() as List<ConstOrder>;
```

Is my inheritance mapping possible? How can I get only ConstOrders?

Answer (score 0):

NH doesn't suport mixin inheritance strategies.